# Break 3d object into two parts

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, 3dsmax

I need to break an 3d object into 2 parts such that the "connection surface" looks realistically. I know there are plenty of cell fracture add ons in blender, but they all create many new flat objects. I need the opposite - only 2 result parts, but many triangles in the surface of break.

I wonder if there is any simple functionality in blender, 3dsmax, or directly in unity. I am also thinking of creating at first the surface (e.g. Bezier surface) and then somehow "cut" the object by intersecting this surface through the object.

I am pretty new to 3d graphics and I am not familiar with the tools and engines, so for me it doesn't matter, which tool I will use, just need to do this procedure. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Something like [the bisect tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bisect.html)? The [knife tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife.html) also has a cut through option but won't fill in the areas between the cut faces.

Comment: @sambler "The Bisect tool is a quick way to cut a mesh in two along a custom plane." my goal is to divide the object along a custom surface, not just a plane.